# SUM of 2 other SUMs from 2 similar tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table 'A', table 'B' and table 'C'

A:

```
|Name|ID|
|AAA |Z5|
|AAB |Z5|
|BBB |F2|
...
```

B:

```
|ID|QTY|PRICE|
|Z5|5  |5.123|
|Z5|3  |2.222|
|Q0|9  |3.111|
```

C:

```
|ID|QTY|PRICE|
|Z5|8  |4.3  |
|F2|3  |0.55 |
```

Result I need:

A:

```
|Name|ID|SUM   |
|AAA |Z5|64.459|
|AAB |Z5|64.459|
|BBB |F2|1.65  |
```

It sums everything it finds in other 2 tables as a total

I tried some cases of inner join for both B and A.
Tried some cases of Union.
With inner join i end up with too little results i should get(some cases from B and C get cut out(or A, not 100% sure))
With Union i get a lot of duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `union all` before joining:

```
select a.name, a.id, sum(total)
from a left join
     ((select b.id, sum(b.qty * b.price) as total
       from b
       group by b.id
      ) union all
      (select c.id, sum(c.qty * c.price) as total
       from c
       group by c.id
      )
     ) bc
group by a.name, a.id;
```

Comment: I end up with some duplicates
```A:
|Name|ID|SUM   |
|AAA |Z5|30.059|
|AAB |Z5|30.059|
|AAA |Z5|34.4    |
|AAB |Z5|34.4    |
|BBB |F2|1.65    |
|...
```

Comment: @Tohrii . . . This query cannot produce duplicates on name/id because of the outer `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.name, a.id, sum(bc.total) as total
from a left join
     (select b.id, b.qty * b.price as total
        from b
      union all
      select c.id, c.qty * c.price as total
        from c
      ) bc on a.id = bc.id
group by a.name, a.id;
```

It is arguable to also do or don't aggregation on **bc** level, but I prefer not to, to keep code cleaner.

Comment: I end up with some duplicates ```A: |Name|ID|SUM | |AAA |Z5|30.059| |AAB |Z5|30.059| |AAA |Z5|34.4 | |AAB |Z5|34.4 | |BBB |F2|1.65 | |...```